# Schedule Post, Publishing post on wrong time (in wordpress Subsites)

Tags: php, wordpress

I have multi-site wordpress and in that there are several sub-sites. So when schedule a post with 22 hrs OR 24 hrs etc. Its get publish on wrong time like sometime 30 Mins delay, sometime 1 Hrs delay and sometime 12 Hours before actual schedule date. Not a consistence time difference.
I do set time zone exactly what needed, So no time zone issue.
Time is set to 24 Hrs format.
Please suggest!!

Answer (score 0):

try this plugin to Fix Failed Future Posts,

```
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-missed-schedule/faq/
```